# Fill diagonals of array with same values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given `n` and `values` array (`values.length = 2 * n - 1`), I want to fill an array of `n x n` elements, in a way that its diagonals will have the same values as follows:

ex. n = 3, values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:

```
0 1 2
3 0 1
4 3 0

arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0]
```

ex. n = 4, values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

```
0 1 2 3
4 0 1 2
5 4 0 1
6 5 4 0

arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 6, 5, 4, 0]
```

I was able to fill upper half of the array using the following code, but got stuck with the rest:

```
var n = 3;
var values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        a[j * n + i] = values[i - j];
    }
}

/* Result
0 1 2
  0 1
    0

arr = [0, 1, 2, undefined, 0, 1, undefined, undefined, 0]

Expected output:
0 1 2
3 0 1
4 3 0

arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0] */
```

Length of `values` array is `2 * n - 1`, which is the count of diagonals of the array.

Any ideas how to fill the whole array?

Comment: What is the expected output for the script in the question?

Comment: The number of diagonals: Is it `2 * n - 1` - or should it be `2 * (n - 1)`? Because the former with n = 3 is `2 * 3 - 1` which is `6 - 1` = `5`. While the latter is `2 * (3 - 1)` which becomes `2 * 2` = `4`.

Comment: Are you supplied with `arr = []` which contains the elements which must be transformed into a 2D array? Your questions don't line up as in the first 2 examples `arr=[]` has `nxn` elements, however your code has `arr=[]` with 4 elements.

Comment: @jsNoob it is `2 * n - 1`. It is the count of diagonals of an `n * n` array. For 3 x 3 array, it is 5; for 4 x 4 array, it is 7.

Comment: @Nitheesh Added expected output to my question now.

Comment: @NicholasBarfknecht Given: `n` and `values` array. Just added expected output, so that you may better understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

Created while loop and added counter. Counter counts the elements suppose to be cut from end. first loop goes thru these elements and adds them to the beginning, second loop limited by this counter so it doesnt hit the end of the array and it adds the elemets havent been cutted from the array to the end. until all elements are cut from the array.

```
var values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

var a = [];
var ctr = 0
while(ctr < values.length){
  for(let i = (values.length - ctr); i < values.length; i++){
    a.push(values[i]);
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < (values.length - ctr); i++){
    a.push(values[i]);
  }
  ctr++;
}
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]

0 1 2 3 4
4 0 1 2 3
3 4 0 1 2
2 3 4 0 1
1 2 3 4 0
```

Comment: *'Here is the answer'* is not an answer. Explain what you have done and how it addresses the OP's question (if it does, hard to tell).

Comment: Added @pilchard

Comment: Thanks for your input, however this does not give the expected result. I have n and values as input (length of values array is a function of n, namely n * 2 - 1). In your code, you get only values as input.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I saw the requested results and made this snippet below
I use a two dimensional array to be able to check if there is an existing diagonal using x y logic and if there was not, there was a counter that would reference the next array number(`c+1%arr.length`)

**EDIT EXPLAINED**: I saw what was going on then I decided to try only adding when there was no diagonal in that "place".. it works like a charm

```js
var arr=[0,1,2,3,4]

function makeBox(arr,n){
  var toReturn=[], c=0
  for(let i=0;i<n*n;i++){
    let y=(i-(i%n))/n, x=i%n
    let diagonal=toReturn[y-1]?toReturn[y-1][x-1]:undefined
    let isDiagonal=typeof diagonal==="number" //0 is a number
    toReturn[y]?toReturn[y].push(isDiagonal?diagonal:arr[c]):
    toReturn[y]=[isDiagonal?diagonal:arr[c]]
    if(!isDiagonal){c=(c+1)%arr.length}
  }
  return toReturn.map(a=>a.join(' ')).join('\n')
}

console.log(makeBox(arr,3))
console.log(makeBox(arr,4))
console.log(makeBox(arr,6))
console.log("before you say that it doesn't work.. you just need the correctly sized array\nLook Below")
console.log(makeBox([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],4))
```

Comment: +1 for Awesome effort. Only thing is the OP has a different expectation for the set of lower/left-side-of-center diagonals.

Comment: huh.. you're right I now checked.. but I do wonder if the question only wants the diagonals.. still gonna try to get the horizontal logic too ;[

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, if you inspect my expected output and examples, the left lower half of the array is different. For n = 3, my expected output is [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0], but yours is [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0].

Comment: so it's not just about the diagonal values confirmed :{ ok gonna work on the vertical values

Comment: The edited version looks more like it. Please let me do a few more tests and then I will accept this as answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Presented below is one possible implementation that achieves the desired objective:

```js
const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

const getCustomArray = (n = 3, val = values) => {
  const res = [...Array(n)].map(x => [...Array(n).fill(-1)]);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i][i] = val[0];
    for (let j = 1; i + j < n; j++) {
      res[i][i+j] = val[j];
      res[i+j][i] = val[n + j - 1]
    }
  }
  return res.map(r => r.join(' ')).join('\n');
};

console.log('3 x 3 array:\n' + getCustomArray());

console.log('4 x 4 array:\n'+ getCustomArray(4, [...Array(2 * 4 -1).keys()]));

console.log('5 x 5 array:\n'+ getCustomArray(5, [...Array(2 * 5 -1).keys()]));

console.log('9 x 9 array:\n'+ getCustomArray(9, [...Array(2 * 9 -1).keys()]));
```

**Approach**

- First, an array of `n` rows & `n` columns is created & filled with some value (such as `-1`).
- Next, the `i` for-loop iterates over the set of diagonals
- The `0,0`, `1,1`, `2,2` diagonal elements are set to the first element of the `values` array (typically `0`).
- Now, a second `j` for-loop iterates.
- It updates the upper & lower diagonals.
- `res[i][i+j]` targets the upper diagonals (such as `0,1`, `1,2`, `2,3`, ...) and populates using `values` array
- `res[i+j][j]` targets the lower diagonals (such as `1,0`, `2,1`, `3,2`, ...) and populates by using an `offset` of `n - 1` to index the `values` array

Please add any questions or feedback on the comments.

Comment: Technically, one does not need to create an initial array (filled with -1). Instead making `let res = [];` should work just the same. However, it helps to visualize when debugging to have the right-sized array to start-with.

Comment: very interesting.. interesting approach too

Comment: hm.. however if the `n>arr.length` strange results happen(probably because of a lot of `undefined`) things that just end up as blank... `getCustomArray(6,[0,1,2,3,4])` makes a triangle for example

Comment: Thank you @TheBombSquad. Good observation. From the question OP states: `Length of values array is 2 * n - 1`. So, if `n` is 6 then the `values` array needs to have 11 elements (say `[0, 1, ... 10]`).